# Mocked unit test error: Expected '<Success.' but was '<>', why is my controller returning an empty ResponseEntity when it is mocked to return Success?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I am trying to test my controller method and have used the approach I have used for my other controllers successfully. I am unsure why it is returning an empty ResponseEntity <> because I am clearly mocking the service to return "Success.".

```
 @Test
        public void addGameSuccessfully() throws Exception {
            GameDTO gameDTO = new GameDTO(1L, 2L, GameResult.VICTORY.getResult());
            doReturn(true).when(userService).userExistsWithId(1L);
            doReturn(true).when(userService).userExistsWithId(2L);
    
            when(gameService.addGame(gameDTO)).thenReturn("Success.");
    
            String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(gameDTO);
    
            MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/games/add-game")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(json).characterEncoding("utf-8"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();
    
            String response = mvcResult.getResponse().getContentAsString();
            assertEquals("Success.", response);
       }
```

Controller method:

```
/**
 * Create a Game entity to record a game that has been played.
 *
 * @param gameDTO the game dto to create a Game entity from.
 * @return the response entity indicating success/failure.
 */
@PostMapping("/add-game")
public ResponseEntity<?> addGame(@RequestBody final GameDTO gameDTO) {
    if (!userService.userExistsWithId(gameDTO.getUser1.getUserId)) || !userService.userExistsWithId(gameDTO.getUser2.getUserId())) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Failed to create a game because the user/users do/does not exist.");
    }
    String msg = gameService.addGame(gameDTO);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(msg);
}
```

The test fails due to an assertion error: expected: <Success.> but was: <>

I also tried adding a System.out.println() to print the gameDTO object property values in the GameController method and successfully printed these values so it has the right gameDTO.

I am very confused because I have used this same approach on other controllers and all have been successful.

Also, other tests in the GameControllerTest class work fine so its not an issue with configuration etc.

Edit: Postman test works btw:
[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How is the 'equals method' of GameDTO defined?

Comment: @sigur I don't understand what you mean, GameDTO has no defined Equals method.

Comment: @sigur I have also added Postman test showing it works correctly

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the mocked gameService instance inside the controller? Because otherwise the controller is not going to call the mocked method but the actual implementation.

Can you provide the test setup?

Comment: What's the meaning of Postman test?! How can you execute the method @Test "addGameSuccessfully" by Postman? I suspect by Postman you're calling the actual API running, not the unit test.